# Is there a limit on number of requests to Chrome history API from an extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I was browsing through Chrome extension gallery I saw one author mentioned something about some possible limits on how many times you can search Chrome history through API. Is it true? I can't find any info on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true at all, it is possible that he didn't declare the appropriate permissions to History in the .json file, and instead used a background page...

In the `manifest.json` file you are supposed to give the extension [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html)... One of these permissions is to access the history file...

The permissions part of the `json file` that will allow access to the history file looks like this:

```
"permissions": [ "history" ]
```

And once you have access to the History file, You'll be able to use the [search API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#method-search) as follows in your background page:

```
chrome.history.search(object query, function callback)
```

As long as your background page is running - which is whenever the browser is open - You'll be able to make as many searches as you please...